# Gatsby E-commerce website cache issue with frequent builds

Tags: node.js, caching, build, e-commerce, gatsby

I've built a large e-commerce website with around 1000 products in gatsby which we are deploying every day, sometimes multiple times per day but the problem we are having is that after each update users have problems with content, the links not working and other things like images not showing. However, when you clear the cache or open the website in incognito mode (sometimes on refresh the page) then it's working properly.

I've tried to add this code into the gatsby-browser.js file, but it didn't fix this issue.

```
export function onServiceWorkerUpdateReady(){window.location.reload(true)};
```